# Body parameter required with swagger 4.0 Asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I am using a swagger 4.0 with Asp.net core 2.2 Web Api. I want to tell the swagger UI on post/put method that some of the body content parameters are required. As I know that if the parameter is query parameter then it is required. Done some research https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-request-body/ and found that the body content can be made required

[image: swagger document]

Some of the research from other link

[How to mark a property as required in Swagger, without ASP.NET model validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53319588/how-to-mark-a-property-as-required-in-swagger-without-asp-net-model-validation)

[How can I tell Swashbuckle that the body content is required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141137/how-can-i-tell-swashbuckle-that-the-body-content-is-required)

**Controller code**

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]LearningApplication model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return InvalidModelState(ModelState);

            // create the record,no need to provide resource auth as only admin can action this controller
            await _learningApplicationManager.CreateAsync(model, LearningApplicationValidator.OnCreateRuleset);

            return Created(url, model);
        }
```

**Model**

```
public class LearningApplication : BaseAuditableWithLogicalDeleteAggregate<Guid>
    {

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "You must enter the name of the course or professional Learning session")]
        [DataMember]
        public string CourseName { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "You must enter the professional Learning provider: ie. TGS, AGSV, etc")]
        [DataMember]
        public string Provider { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string EventWebsite { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string RegistrationExpenses { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide the Start Date & time")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? StartDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

**Current Swagger display**

[image: current swagger]

Comment: Are you comparing a JSON Schema with a JSON object? The parameter is required, and a JSON object will not tell you that

Comment: No, I am not comparing JSON Schema  with a JSON object. Just I want to show the required attribute.

Comment: That's exactly shown in a JSON Schema, not in a JSON object. An object will only have data, a schema will tell you how the data should be formatted. Since "required" is an attribute and not a value, you cannot know that from an object

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to generate a JSON Schema from the code in SwashBuckle?